# ESP8266 with NodeMCU responds only 3 times

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a simple Lua script that creates a server that listens for messages. The script flips the output of two GPIOs when the message is 'led1' or 'led2'. The problem is that the script works for only 2 or 3 times. I will be back with actual script.

Edit 1: The script for the server is the following (the GPIO part was removed to simplify the script):

```
wifi.setmode(1)
wifi.sta.config("my_router","12345678")
tmr.delay(3000000)
print(wifi.sta.getip())

s=net.createServer(net.TCP)
s:listen(433,function(conn)
    conn:on("receive",function(conn,payload)
        print(payload)
    conn:send("received")
    end)
    conn:on("sent",function(conn) conn:close() end)
end)
```

The result is the following (if i send 'led1' to server more than 3 times):

```
>192.168.0.117 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1
>led1
>led1
>led1
```

After this, the client says 'connection timed out' but the ESP8266 still works (at least the serial lines)

Comment: And error messages if any. Does the NodeMCU reboot?

Comment: The question is pointless until you show us the actual code.

Comment: I know. For the moment i just wanted to know if this kind of problem appeared to anyone else. More to come

Comment: No, NodeMCU does not reboot, serial works just after and indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tmr.delay` of 3 secs will screw up the wifi stack.  Use a `tmr.alarm` and hang your main processing off that. This example worked fine for me:

```
do
  local srv = net.createServer(net.TCP)
    srv:listen(8888, function(sk)
      sk:on("receive", function(sk, rec)
      print("Received ", rec)
      sk:send("echo "..rec, sk.close)
    end)
  end)
  function close() srv:close() end
end
```

The last arg to the send is just a completion callback to close the socket. You will also need to close the `srv` to free up the reference to the listener function in the Lua registery.

*Make sure that you use a current `dev` build from the nodeMCU cloud builder*.

Comment: I can't believe i did this kind of mistake. In 12 hours i will test it and tell you the result! Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, that delay was the problem. Works like a charm now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to Terry's answer.

As he said the main issue is your `tmr.delay(3000000)`. There's a reason why it accepts *micro* seconds and not milliseconds. Here's an excerpt from the [API documentation](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/tmr/#tmrdelay):

> This is in general a **bad** idea, because nothing else gets to run, and
>   the networking stack (and other things) can fall over as a result. The
>   only time tmr.delay() may be appropriate to use is if dealing with a
>   peripheral device which needs a (very) brief delay between commands,
>   or similar. *Use with caution!*

The reason why you added the delay in the first place is because you want to wait until the WiFi stack is fully initialized (i.e. IP assigned). What you want to do instead is to set up a `tmr.alarm` that "loops" in 1s intervals until WiFi is ready. Here's an abbreviated example from https://cknodemcu.wordpress.com:

```
--init.lua
function startup()
    -- do stuff here
end

print("set up wifi mode")
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config(SSID,PASSWORD)
wifi.sta.connect()
tmr.alarm(1, 1000, 1, function() 
    if wifi.sta.getip() == nil then 
        print("IP unavaiable, Waiting...") 
    else 
        tmr.stop(1)
        print("Config done, IP is "..wifi.sta.getip())
        print("You have 5 seconds to abort Startup")
        print("Waiting...")
        tmr.alarm(0, 5000, 0, startup)
    end 
 end)
```

Instead of checking for `wifi.sta.getip()` you might as well check for [`wifi.sta.status() == 5`](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/wifi/#wifistastatus) like I do in an [old Gist](https://gist.github.com/marcelstoer/63ce6e6d78cef435d2ec).

Also, take a look at the [net module API documentation](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/net/).